# Why do I get a deadlock warning for a simple job on a cloud file?

Tags: finder, file-transfer, cron

I have a file that sits on a Cloud directory managed by a cloud storage service that uses the Apple [FileProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) API. No, this is not iCloud, but this is apparently the same API framework in use.

The desire is that since the API doesn't allow me to pin/favorite a file to prevent it from swapping out to the cloud, I've set up a simple `cron` job that once-an-hour will do this:

`cat /Users/myusername/Library/CloudStorage/CloudDrive-Documents/neverswap.txt >/dev/null`

I figure that as long as I'm regularly accessing the file, it'll never swap out, right? Unfortunately, it seems like I regularly find this error being spit out by cron:

`cat: /Users/myusername/Library/CloudStorage/CloudDrive-Documents/neverswap.txt: Resource deadlock avoided`

So my question is:

1. Why is this simple job sometimes resulting in a deadlock? And a deadlock of *what*?
2. I suspect UNIX tools like `cat` don't communicate with the FileProvider API and only the Finder seems to know how to trigger things, is this correct?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

thanks